# WCF Proxy Class

Tags: c#, wcf, proxy

I have in a project am working on, a couple Model Classes where most of them inherit from one base class, The base class is marked with the  attribute with Sub Classes Types.

In my Service, the function returns an Object of the base class, the implementation of the function will of course return one of the sub Classes.

When i use Visual Studio for Creating the proxy Classes it will only create the Base Class in the proxy without any of the sub classes since there is no method in the Service that will return an Instance of the sub class directly.

my question Is there a way to force the proxy Generator to generate the classes for Sub Classes even if they aren't used directly in the service?

Comment: Did you manage to solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Use the ServiceKnownTypeAttribute:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(ResponseType1))]
[KnownType(typeof(ResponseType2))]
public class BaseResponseType
{
    ...
}

[DataContract]
public class ResponseType1: BaseResponseType
{
    ...
}

[DataContract]
public class ResponseType2: BaseResponseType
{
    ...
}
```

Then your service operation:

```
[OperationContract]
BaseResponseType ProcessSomething (Something thing);
```